# Pressure drop in very low reynolds number flows

Tags: fluid-mechanics

The wikipedia article for the Darcy Weisbach pressure drop equation states that "In effect, the friction loss in the laminar regime is more accurately characterized as being proportional to flow velocity, rather than proportional to the square of that velocity: one could regard the Darcy–Weisbach equation as not truly applicable in the laminar flow regime."

What pressure drop equation would be more appropriate for flow with Reynolds numbers 1-100?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Googling "pressure drop laminar flow" gives a Wikipedia link to the ["Hagen-Poiseuille" equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hagen%E2%80%93Poiseuille_equation) for laminar flow through circular pipes.

Does that answer your question?

Comment: Well, thats embarrassing. I had googled 10 versions of "pressure drop low reynolds number" without ever including the word laminar.

Comment: @ericksonla No worries.  I kinda just assumed you hadn't even really tried, so I was a bit salty with my answer; but that makes sense.  The reason "low Reynolds number" probably didn't get hits was because Reynolds number isn't really as important in laminar flow relative to turbulent.  The search engine probably kept finding the words "Reynolds number" with "pressure drop" and that drowned out anything to do with low Reynolds numbers (where the term "laminar" would be more common).